# Can I print rational numbers(Fractional) in floating point and in a/b format in the same time ?C++

Tags: c++, function, class

**Can I print rational numbers(Fractional) in floating point and in a/b format in the same time ?** 
 if I can , How to create it in two function ?

Comment: How is your input of fractional numbers?

Comment: yes only if a and b are given.

Comment: `printf('%f %d, %d\n', a/b, a, b)`, basically

Comment: `printf('%f %d/%d\n', a/b, a, b);` marc

Comment: @MarcB: Might be disappointed w/ floating point part if `a` & `b` are integers.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor for example 1/2 , I wanna print in 1/2 and 0.5

Comment: Come on guys !  It's a C++ tag !  I'd expected `cout << (double)a/b <<  " "<<a<<"/"<<b<<endl;`  ;-)

Comment: @ScottHunter: can't do ALL their homework for them...

Comment: @Christophe please make it a class and a function

Comment: @Christophe It's C++ and then you use C-style casts?

Comment: Practically speaking, a floating point in binary representation is a fraction of a power of 2 (https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DataRepresentation.html). So it would be possible to diplay any floating point as a fraction.  The algortithm would depend on floating point representation.